# Django Slug Generated URL Returning: 'No Fund matches the given query.'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to use a slug to generate urls, however wherever I visit the url I get 'Page not found at /funds/[slug_generated_value]'

```
Raised by:  apps.funds.views.details
No Fund matches the given query
```

Here is my models.py, I generate fund_id using Fund.name to create an acronym and add the datetime value from deadline minus the hour, min, sec values:

```
class Fund(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Fund, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OfferedFunds(models.Model):
    fund_id = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True)
    fund_name = models.ForeignKey(Fund)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField('Deadline')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        output = ''
        for i in self.fund_name.name.upper().split():
            output += i[0]
        deadline = str(self.deadline)[:-15] 
        deadline = deadline.replace('-', '')
        random_number = random.randint(1,9)
        self.fund_id = '%s%s%s' % (output, deadline, random_number)
        self.slug = slugify(self.fund_id)
        super(OfferedFunds, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Offered funds"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.fund_id)
```

And my corresponding views.py:

```
def details(request, slug):
    context_dict = {}

    fund = get_object_or_404(Fund, slug=slug)
    context_dict['fund'] = fund

    offered_funds = OfferedFunds.objects.filter(fund_name=fund, deadline__gte=timezone.now()).order_by('deadline')
    context_dict['offered_funds'] = offered_funds

    return render(request, 'funds/details.html', context_dict)

def of_details(request, slug):
    context_dict = {}

    of = get_object_or_404(OfferedFunds, slug=slug)
    context_dict['of'] = of

    return render(request, 'funds/offered-funds-details.html', context_dict)
```

And finally my urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.details, name='details'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.of_details, name='of details'),
```

My details() view works fine, however its the of_details() that does not work. If I take out the details() view, the of_details() works. Anyone know How I can solve this error? Thanks

Comment: How is Django to differentiate between your identical URLs?

Comment: Your two regexes are identical, so when Django searches for an applicable URL match it will always implement the `view.details` function

Comment: Yup, thats it. Changed to `1r'^det/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$'` and it works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so as pointed out in the comments by user [lambo477](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4907767/lambo477) my urls were too alike, so I changed:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.of_details, name='of details'),
```

to:

```
url(r'^det/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.of_details, name='of details'),
```

and that worked.